# How can I pass a filter into an angular directive to be used in an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set up a directive so that I can pass in both the data to be used in the directive, and the specific filter that will be used in the ng-repeat inside of it.  This isn't working, so I assume I'm approaching the whole problem wrong.

How do I pass in the filter?  Alternatively, how do I prefilter/sort the list I'm passing in?

(The scope must be isolated, because I want to have multiple lists on the same page.)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
myApp.controller('mainPage',function($scope){
    $scope.cars = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];
    });
myApp.directive('carList',function(){
    return {
        scope: {
        listOfCars: '=',
        carFilter : '@'
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<table>\
    <tr ng-repeat="{{carFilter}}">\
    <td>{{car}}</td>\
    </tr>\
    </table>'
    };
});
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainPage">
<car-list list-of-cars="cars" car-filter='car in listOfCars | orderBy:"toString()"' ></car-list>
</body>
</html>
```

Plunker with the above code in it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ipsF15?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I *think* this is a workable solution - rather than passing in the filter, pass in the filtered list like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
myApp.controller('mainPage',function($scope){
    $scope.cars = ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];
    });
myApp.directive('carList',function(){
    return {
        scope: {
        listOfCars: '&',
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<table>\
    <tr ng-repeat="car in listOfCars()">\
    <td>{{car}}</td>\
    </tr>\
    </table>'
    };
});
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainPage">
<car-list list-of-cars="cars | orderBy:'toString()' | limitTo:2 " ></car-list>
</body>
</html>
```

Which doesn't feel very intuitive.  Is this the right approach?