# how can I pass a filter to a directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326853/how-can-i-pass-a-filter-into-an-angular-directive-to-be-used-in-an-ng-repeat), I have a directive that I want to use in a couple different situations.  I'm passing in a value that it will work with, but I'd also like to pass in a filter to apply to it.  What's the right syntax for doing this?

```
app.directive('showMe', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      value: '=',
      filter: '=',
      placeholder: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'show-me.html'
  };
});
```

template:

```
<input ng-model="value" ng-show="editMode" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />
<p ng-hide="editMode">{{(value | percent)||placeholder}}</p>
```

use:

```
<show-me value="item.discount" filter="percent" placeholder="0%" />
```

expected result:

```
<input value="25" placeholder="0%" />
or
<p>25%</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this at a basic level by using the method below; simply use the filter provider within your directive controller, to parse the given value. For example:

```
<my-directive value="1461782417" filter="date"></my-directive>
```

Within "myDirective" you could implement the filter very easily like this:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span>{{displayValue}}</span>',
    scope: {
      value: '=',
      filter: '='
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
      // Pass the value
      $scope.displayValue = $filter($scope.filter)($scope.value);
    }]
  });
```

Comment: Yes, that worked for me.  I encapsulated the displayValue in a function, though so that it dealt with more situations: `return $scope.value ? ($scope.filter ? $filter($scope.filter)($scope.value) : $scope.value) : $scope.placeholder;`

Comment: As per the AngularJS documentation, you could extend this even further if you desired. Filters can take the following arguments`$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)` (the first argument, "array", being `$scope.value`)

Answer (score 0):

```
    .filter('percent', function () {
        return function (text, length, end) {
            if (text == null || text == '') text = '0';
            text = parseInt(text) / 100;
            return text.toFixed(2);
    };
```

Comment: Um, no - I have a filter to perform the transformation.  I'm asking how to pass it into the directive to be used.